# variable number of arguments in ndgrid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product

I would like to generate a matrix of references. This code works but I would like to use a variable size of set. I can't manage that... Thanks for helping !

```
cpt = 1;
for ll = 1: 3
    nb_rules = 5;
    sets{cpt} = [1 : nb_rules];
    cpt = cpt +1;
end

[x y z] = ndgrid(sets{:});% Here begins the trouble :
mat_ref = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];% what if size is not 3 ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `cell`-array `GRID` on the receiving end, to get a programmatic [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-14):

```
N = numel(sets);
[GRID{1:N}] = ndgrid(sets{:});
mat_ref = reshape(cat(N+1,GRID{:}),[],N)
```

(No need to declare `GRID = cell(..)` first.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this lesson !! It's perfect !

Comment: @BPulsart: If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it to turn it green.